# How to set a camera position that bounds a polyline route after display it in the map?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps-android-api-2

How can I show the area covered by the painted route on the map after add the PolylineOption?. How can I get a similar code in Android like the next line for iOS or a better solution?:

`[self.mapa setVisibleMapRect:[polyLine boundingMapRect] animated:YES];`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I add my PolylineOptions and then move the Camera with :

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 50));
```

The camera position bounds the polyline route.

Is that what you want to do ?

Pierre.